# Powershell script to dynamically replace text in console as it is displayed

Tags: windows, postgresql, powershell, scripting, console

Is it possible to use powershell scripting to scan all console output in a powershell window, before it is outputted, and replace certain words with other words so that the altered output is displayed in the console?

My use case is that if I replace null with an ANSI colored null, the special chars are escaped on display. I want to unescape them on display to show in color.

For example;
\pset null '[91m[0m'

displays null in the console as 
\x1B[91m\x1B[0m

So I would wish replace all instances of this with a delicious ANSI colored null everywhere in the console window.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share some code? What did you try?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have anything. I've been researching how to capture all output from the console in a function but I can't find anything that does what I need. The powershell documentation is very terse.

Comment: Can you share screenshot or make your question clearer? Where did the output comes from? Is it from another powershell script? What do you mean by saying "colored null"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about scanning output, but you can always "-replace" anything that might generate output:

e.g.

{write-host "Hey, this is stuff"} -replace "stuff","things"

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\windows\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll") -replace "4.0.0.0","3.1415"